# What kind of audio file should i use for iOS Apps?

Tags: ios, audio, audioformat

I'm working on an app that will play several audio files. I have gotten that to work, having no trouble. But I'm not sure what file format to use. Right now I am using .wav and one .mp3. Is there a file type that is recommended? I don't know how the app is packaged for the App Store; should the audio be compressed or uncompressed?

Thank you!

Comment: I wish the down voter had explained why. Perhaps this question would have been better asked more specifically, like what audio formats does Apple's iOS frameworks support, does software-based or hardware-assisted come with any penalties (e.g. latency, energy), or what codecs have a hardware-assisted path? Anyway @abhishek-arora has a link to the best answer to those sorts of questions. AAC, HE-AAC, ALAC, and MP3 have had hardware assisted paths from the start; ALAC is lossless (full quality) and compressed (small); AAC is highest quality lossy and smaller than MP3; HE-AAC is smallest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Personally, I favor compression unless quality is an issue. Mp3s, while lossy is my preferred default. It's a standard file type, easy to work with, it can be high quality and iPhone/iOS is efficient at decoding.

However, if you need higher quality, AAC or uncompressed can be better. It's also possible for an mp3 to take a fraction of a second before it starts to play due to decoding. That may or may not be an issue if your audio is tied to a UI event.

Comment: I talked to my uncle and arrived at a conclusion that compression would be better, unless maybe like you said if you needed better quality. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1):

An app bundle is the most common way of packaging the executable code(though not the only way.)
I will recommend you to read the following to know about how the bundle structure is.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1

With regards to the audio file format, There is no favourite as such for apple. You can find the preferred list of audio formats as:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW9

Hope this solves your problems.